# Swift Dictionary filled but still empty

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary

I've been sitting on a problem for too long and I really don't understand why this is happening. I've searched on the web for solutions and I have tried every single one of them and still I get this problem. I initialize a dictionary in Swift and then I add some values to it, but right after I've added the keys/values the dictionary is empty (checking in debug mode), also nil later on in the code when trying to read from it. This is my current code:

I first get the plist where I want to add my dictionary:

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Questions", ofType: "plist")
var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)!
var questionsArr = dict.objectForKey("Math") as NSArray
var questionsMutableArray:NSMutableArray = questionsArr.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
```

Then I create and add values to my dictionary

```
//I have also tried with this and got the same result: var newDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
var newDict = [String: String]()
newDict["Question"] = "What is 1+1"
newDict["A"] = "One"
newDict["B"] = "Two"
newDict["C"] = "Three"
```

The newDict seems empty in debug mode right here.
Then I write the dictionary to my plist:

```
questionsMutableArray.addObject(newDict)
questionsMutableArray.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
```

Later on in the code I get my plist like this (which worked before when I had not added the newDict:

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Questions", ofType: "plist")
var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)!
```

On the last line (NSDictinoary(contentsOfFile:path!)! I get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? 
Help would be appreciated!

**EDIT** Solution in **4)**

```
1. I'm getting an array of dictionaries from my plist (Questions).
2. I add a new dictionary to my array of dictionaries.
3. I write/save it to the plist.
4. I get the array from the plist again and investigate the content of it.
5. The new dictionary I just added is not there.
```

This is the code:

**1)** questionsArr is empty

```
var bundlepath:NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Questions", ofType: "plist")!

        var dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlepath)!
        var questionsArr = dict.objectForKey("Math") as NSArray
        var questionsMutableArray:NSMutableArray = questionsArr.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray
```

**2)**  questionsMutableArray was empty and now has the new question in it.

```
var newDict = [String: String]()
    newDict["QuestionTitle"] = "What is 1+1?"
    newDict["A"] = "One"
    newDict["B"] = "Two"
    newDict["C"] = "Three"

let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
var path:NSString = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Questions.plist");

questionsMutableArray.addObject(newDict)
dict["Math"] = questionsMutableArray
```

**3)**

```
let didItSave = dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

**4)** questionsArr is still empty. If I use 'path' instead of 'bundlepath' it works!

```
dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlepath)! //<- I USED 'path' INSTEAD OF 'bundlepath' and now it works!
    questionsArr = dict.objectForKey("Math") as NSArray
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you find it's nil. The posted code doesn't help to identify the issue

Comment: Not sure how it works in swift, but your dictionary need to be "mutable" if you want to add stuff to it.

Comment: The mutability of a collection in Swift is determined by whether you assigned the dictionary to a variable or constant, not by the class name as in Objective-C.

Comment: It's likely that NSDictionary cannot load the file. Make sure the path is correct.

Comment: I have edited my question. How do I initialize a mutable dictionary and add items to it? The path is correct.

Comment: Your plist file is an array of dictionaries, so when you retrieve it, you must retrieve it as an NSArray.

Comment: Could it be that you've defined an instance property named 'newDict' in the class definition and then are creating another variable named 'newDict' that will get freed as soon as viewDidLoad returns.

Comment: First, actually look in the file system for the plist file and see if its contents make sense (should be a sort of XML representation of the data).  Based on that work forward or backward to the point of failure.

Comment: Double check that the path variable is not-nil.  Check that the Questions.plist file is included in the app bundle.

Comment: The path is correct and I've always used it. Only when I write my newDic to the path it gets this error. The problem is that the dictionary doesn't even fill up with my values, it's just empty when I debug and examine it.

Comment: The path continues to be correct.  The issue is that the plist root element is now an array, because that is what you wrote there.  The original was a dictionary.  The nil is in the cast of an array to a dictionary.  If you check my answer, you'll see that you need to reserve the entire dictionary.

Comment: @JeremyPope I will check later on when I have a computer and let you know as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write iOS Bundle. iOS Bundle is read only you cannot write.

I would recommend you to write in Document directory
Try this way

```
 var bundlepath:NSString= NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Questions", ofType: "plist")

    var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlepath)!
    var questionsArr = dict.objectForKey("Math") as NSArray
    var questionsMutableArray:NSMutableArray = questionsArr.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray


    //I have also tried with this and got the same result: var newDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
    var newDict = [String: String]()
    newDict["Question"] = "What is 1+1"
    newDict["A"] = "One"
    newDict["B"] = "Two"
    newDict["C"] = "Three"

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    var path:NSString = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Questions.plist");



questionsMutableArray.addObject(newDict)
```

//assign array back to dictionary.
dict["Math"]=questionsMutableArray

```
dict.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)

    var dictFromDisk = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)!
```

Comment: I get this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when doing the third line.

Comment: Basically what you are trying to do load the plist from bundle and add dictionary to array and the save to disk. But you have to load the plist file from Document directory for next read then your data will be consistent.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and let you know. Not able atm. Thank's in advance!

Comment: Ok let me know if any issue I will help you to fix it.

Comment: Hey @Shashi3456643 , On the last line (`var dictFromDisk = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:path)!`) I get this error again: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. writeToFile seems to work since it says writetofile success.

Comment: Give me some time I will compile and update me answer

Comment: I try with this code instead to see my Math-questions-array of dictionaries after I've saved the new one: `dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: bundlepath)!;
questionsArr = dict.objectForKey("Sports") as NSArray`. And when I print it my new dictionary is not there.

Comment: It should be NSMutableArray Not NSDictionary because you are saving array not dictionary. var arrayFromDisk = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)!

Comment: I have updated my answer. In order to get dictionary you need to save NSDictionary and get NSDictionary from disk

Comment: Again I updated my answer now saving NSDictionary and getting NSDictionary. It should be fine.

Comment: Did you try? Let me know

Comment: It's running now and getting the dict out from disk, but my new dictionary (What is 1+1, one,two,three) is not there. It's like it's never saved even though it is before I writeToFile!

Comment: I have updated now check your array was not assigning back to dictionary.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you so much Shashi, you have helped very much, I'm greatful! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

First when you retrieve the plist, retrieve it to an NSMutableDictionary

```
var dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)!
```

Then once you have your array created, set your dictionary Math key to it.

```
dict["math"] = questionsMutableArray
```

Then write the dictionary back to your path.  May want to see if it worked, writeToFile returns a bool.

```
let didItSave = dict.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
```

Comment: This works to the `writeToFile` part. I can see that my new dictionary is saved in the `dict["math"]`. But after i write it to file and then get it again (read the plist), the new dict is not there!

Answer (score 0):

Your plist file is an array of dictionaries, so when you retrieve it, you must retrieve it as an NSArray and then cast it as an array of `Dictionary<String, String>`

```
let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Questions", ofType: "plist")!) as [[String: String]]
```

Then you access a specific dictionary in this array using:

```
let someDict = array[someIndex]
```

Comment: My "Root"-key in Question.plist is a Dictionary that contains Arrays which also contains many dictionaries each.

Comment: Why not just make your root object an array?

Comment: I don't know actually why I did this, but now it is like that. The problem is that my newDict is empty after I've initialized it and added items to it. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited my answer:**

You are saving an array with the following line

```
questionsMutableArray.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
```

but then trying to load it as a dictionary.  You should set the questions array to the "Math" key of the dictionary and then save the dictionary itself like this to make your reads and writes compatible.

```
dict["Math"] = questionsMutableArray 
dict.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
```

Comment: My "Root"-key in Question.plist is a Dictionary that contains Arrays which also contains many dictionaries each.

Comment: You're reading questions from dict["math"], but you are adding the new ones to a different array and replacing your old plist with that array. So, your plist file isn't a dictionary anymore. Your current writes and reads aren't compatible. Please check my edited answer to solve the problem